# Podman Desktop is unable to initialize

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, podman

After installing Podman Desktop on Windows and trying to initialize podman machine, the process stops at "initializing" status (no error).

When trying to manually ininitialize the machine (via CLI), an error is returned:

> error: package permissions restore of shadow-utils on guest os failed: exit status 0xffffffff

or

> error: the WSL import of guest OS failed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to solved my issue with the info described at https://www.techtutsonline.com/install-podman-in-windows/#Troubleshooting

```
wsl --set-default-version 2
wsl --unregister podman-machine-default
wsl --shutdown
podman machine init
```

If that doesn't work, try this with a full restart and retry the command above (I needed this command).

```
netsh winsock reset
```

Comment: I also unregistered all my WSL Linux instances. It worked here. Thanks.

Comment: Works for me on podman 4.8.3, thanks! For me error came by reinstalling podman, seems like is keeping old register.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this while attempting to run Podman on a virtual machine (via VMWare Workstation), which would look as follows in powershell:

```
> podman machine init
Extracting compressed file
Importing operating system into WSL (this may take a few minutes on a new WSL install)...
Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.
For information please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2-install
Error: the WSL import of guest OS failed: exit status 0xffffffff
```

The solution was shut down, go to the settings of the virtual machine, find the processor options, and enable the `Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-V/RVI` option under the "Virtualization Engine" section.